# Not able to connect hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

While connecting to hadoop, getting below error

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider.getProxy()Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/retry/FailoverProxyProvider$ProxyInfo;
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.(RetryInvocationHandler.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.(RetryInvocationHandler.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryProxy.create(RetryProxy.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:510)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2653)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2687)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:170)
    at hrumen.HTest.main(HTest.java:26)*

Below is my code:

```
***Path corepath = new Path("/var/tmp/hactive/core-site.xml");
        Path sitepath = new Path("/var/tmp/hactive/hdfs-site.xml");
        Path yarnpath = new Path("/var/tmp/hactive/yarn-site.xml");
        Path mapredpath = new Path("/var/tmp/hactive/mapred-site.xml");

        Configuration hconf = new Configuration();
        hconf.addResource(corepath);
        hconf.addResource(sitepath);
        hconf.addResource(yarnpath);
        hconf.addResource(mapredpath);

        try{
            DFSAdmin dfadmin = new DFSAdmin(hconf);
            dfadmin.report();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            //System.out.println("[Exception]: "+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }***
```

Here part of hdfs-site.xml

```
...
    <property>
        <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
        <value>mycluster</value>
        <final>true</final>

    </property>
....

    <property>
        <name>dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.mycluster</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider</value>
    </property>
```

In core-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://mycluster</value>
</property>
```

....

Comment: Probably issue with your configuration files.

Comment: No. clusters performing well, while trying to connect from this code alone, facing the issue.
Same code with  single namenode (standalone) cluster working fine, for ha namenode we have to enable any other thing? that is what i need it

Comment: You're running on HA configuration?

Comment: Thanks @saifahmad for your interest, issue got fixed.
Cluster running on hadoop user, the code i was run from root user that is the issue, once i changed into hadoop able to connect cluster from my code

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem when trying to run my application (in Hortonworks). After being stuck - this took a while, so adding here for future reference - the following fixed the problem.

Either add to **pom.xml** (note: version could vary, set accordingly):

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
   <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
   <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

or add:

```
/path/to/hadoop-hdfs-client-<version_number>.jar
```

to your **classpath** so that the **hadoop-hdfs-client** jar gets included at runtime.